# Modify memory of hareware key of HaspFile which is ReadOnly

Tags: hasp

I'd like to ask a question. I know it is possible to modify the memory of a hareware key by modifying HaspFile which is ReadWrite

```
Dim file As HaspFile = hasp.GetFile(HaspFileId.ReadWrite)       
Dim newBytes() AsByte  = New Byte() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}  
status = file.Write(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length)
```

But I'd like to know, is it possible to modify the readonly memory part of the Key without having a Mater key?

It seems not possible to do it via code?

But is it possible to do via Tools such as Vendor Suit?

Thank you very much for your kindness help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [v.5.10 Software Protection and Licensing Guide (emphasis mine)](http://sentineldiscussion.safenet-inc.com/topic/sentinel-hasp-%e2%80%93-v-5-10-software-protection-and-licensing-guide):

> In the context of Sentinel HASP, Read‐only memory (ROM) is a segment
>   of the memory that can contain data that the protection application
>   can access, but cannot overwrite. Sentinel HASP keys contain two ROM
>   segments, one of which contains Sentinel HASP Feature‐based licenses.
>   The second segment provides an area in which vendor‐customized data
>   can be stored. **These segments can only be updated using remote
>   updates.**

The "remote updates" that the documentation is referring to is the "Remote Update System" (RUS), which is the C2V/V2C method of updating a key.

Since a Master Key is required to generate a remote update, that means *a Master Key is required to make modifications to the read-only memory section of a key*.

The only component of the Vendor Suite that is capable of modifying the read-only memory is Business Studio (by creating an order for a remote update).